# Date format on Reporting Services causing Parameter Type Mismatch

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

We are using Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services, whether is it SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2012 or 2014, even on Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online SSRS we have same problem.

We are using English display language, however we use our local region format (Croatian) which has date format `dd.mm.yyyy`. And SSRS rdl file is configured in this way.

Problem is that report (`.rdl`) parametar for date is by default in incorrect format. Original date picker writes date in format: `dd.mm.yyyy` which is correct, however then we have error - `rsReportParameterTypeMismatch`

The temporary solution is to manually override text box by user for date parameter and remove latest character (period) so date than looks like `dd.mm.yyyy`, and then report works.

Is there any solution how to fix this from `report.rdl` side, so that users can use default date picker (with or without last character - period after year) without `rsReportParameterTypeMismatch` error ?

Since the problem persists on CRM Online SSRS (cloud) also, I am not able to modify any server settings there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the Report language property on the Report Element? This will change the formats of dates and integers but will not translate strings.

[image]